# Animate SVG path from <use> tag

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

I'm trying to animate an svg path using [this technique by Jake Archibald](https://jakearchibald.com/2013/animated-line-drawing-svg/)

The technique works well when the svg code is pasted in my document, but fails when I'm referencing the svg from my "defs.svg" file.

My **defs.svg** looks like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <symbol viewBox="0 0 48 50.6" id="icon-result" fill="#FFF">
    <path d="M19 49.4c-2 1.7-5.1 1.5-6.9-.5l-11-12.8c-1.7-2-1.5-5.1.5-6.9 2-1.7 5.1-1.5 6.9.5l11 12.8c1.8 2.1 1.6 5.2-.5 6.9z"/>
    <path d="M13.6 49.4c-2.2-1.5-2.9-4.5-1.4-6.8L39 2.2C40.5 0 43.5-.7 45.8.8c2.2 1.5 2.9 4.5 1.4 6.8L20.3 48.1c-1.4 2.2-4.5 2.8-6.7 1.3z"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

In my code I do the following:

```
<svg class="Dashboard__nav-icon">
  <use xlink:href="/svg/defs.svg#icon-result" />
</svg>
```

When trying to animate the code this way I get null when trying to get the path by using Jake Archibalds technique linked above. Is there a way to get the path while still using a separate defs.svg file and the `<use>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to get the DOM path element via the second `<svg>` element. That is because elements referenced via a `<use>` do not appear in the DOM tree where they are used.  So the following **will not work**:

```
var path = document.querySelector('.Dashboard__nav-icon path');
```

The symbols elements are not visible in the main document's DOM tree.

However you would be able to reference the paths directly via their definition.  But for that to work you would need to inline the `defs.svg` file.

So, if the defs.svg is in the same file, then you would be able to use:

```
var path = document.querySelector('#icon-result path');
```

Comment: This is what I thought would be the case. Thank you, now I know how to move on with this!